# how to set a database .loc function setting many values pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following lines that work fine:

```
dbOut.loc[dbOut["id"] == id, "date"] = datevalue
dbOut.loc[dbOut["id"] == id,"number"] = numbervalue
```

The problem is, each line take too much time to run. I have like 10 lines of that type, so my iteration time is like 15 iterations/second. leaving just one takes it to 150 iterations/second. 
The question is: Is there a way to make only one `.loc` and set each value to each row?

I tried something like:

```
dbOut.loc[dbOut["id"] == id, ["date","number"]] = datevalue, numbervalue
```

but it doesn't work.

I think that maybe there is a way of making the loc first and then apply each value to each column, but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
dbOut.loc[dbOut["id"] == id, ["date", "number"]] = [datevalue, numbervalue]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy`

```
dbout['date'] = np.where(dbout['id'] == id, datevalue,None)
```

Similarly

```
dbout['number'] = np.where(dbout['id'] == id, numbervalue,None)
```

Note : considering id is predefined, replace the None value with some other if required.